# How to add new dynamic route after deployment using nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, static-site

I deployed my site on AWS using nuxt generate with dynamic route. There is no problem on the pages. Now I want to add new route without the whole deployment process.

Here's an example:

```
/post/1
/post/2
/post/3
------- already deployed and works fine ------
/post/4 <- want to add after deployment
```

I manually upload generated `index.html` on `S3` so I can access the file like `/post/4/index.html` but if I tried to `/post/4` it shows a page that is created with `/post/_id.vue`.

I think routing is not updated. ( I do not know what is the routing rule on `/dist` folder )

Is there any way upload new dynamic route without the whole deployment process?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to generate each page before deploy. By default, dynamic routes are ignored by the generate command.

Go to `nuxt.config.js` and find generate key. This is simple example for generate specific site.

```
export default {
  ...
  generate: {
    routes: [
      '/post/1',
      '/post/2',
      '/post/3',
      '/post/4'
    ]
  }
}
```

If you need to generate dynamic routes programmaticaly, you need to write a function.

Check the docs for more information: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/

And lastly, simple example:

```
import BlogService from './services/BlogService.js'
...
export default {
  ...
  generate: {
    routes: () => {
      return BlogService.getPosts().then(response => {
        return response.data.map(post => {
          return '/post/' + post.id
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I already did it. I have questions. Can you deploy nuxt-generated result using Amplify console or amplify publish?

Comment: Do you know how to provide dynamic meta information when the frontend is using SPA (vueJS or react)? I just want to use amplify but amplify support only SPA and it doesnot not support dynamic meta data... like https://prerender.io/

Comment: Ok, The valid option looks like vuepress. Amplify console said that it support VuePress and other (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/welcome.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake on publish.

```
amplify publish // it publish vue application. it means that the target is SPA not Static page webiste
```

I deployed the files on S3 and it works fine.

I tried regarding to below site. I also failed.

https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/mobile/deploy-files-s3-dropbox-amplify-console/

I want to use amplify with nuxt generate together.

Wrong question, there are no right answer anyway.